# Books thumbnails

Tags: discussion, developer-story

Actually, this is not a question; it is feedback about developer story.

In the previous version (on CV at careers.stackoverflow.com) in section "READINGS":

- Was not only title and description
- But also were available thumbnails for books.
- Now readings don't have thumbnails, and it looks not very nice.

[image]

My feedback (not question) is - it would be nice to have such thumbnails again!